# Filtering files in a directory in Java

Tags: java, file, filter

```
public class Sorter {
String dir1 = ("C:/Users/Drew/Desktop/test");
String dir2 = ("C:/Users/Drew/Desktop/");

public void SortingAlgo() throws IOException {

// Declare files for moving
File sourceDir = new File(dir1);
File destDir = new File(dir2);

//Get files, list them, grab only mp3 out of the pack, and sort

File[] listOfFiles = sourceDir.listFiles();

if(sourceDir.isDirectory()) {

for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

    //list Files
    System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);

    String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(dir1);
    System.out.println(ext);



    }
}

}
```

}

I am trying to filter out only .mp3's in my program. I'm obviously a beginner and tried copying some things off of Google and this website. How can I set a directory (sourceDir) and move those filtered files to it's own folder?

Comment: Have you looked at suggested solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java]  or here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758268/java-move-file-with-certain-file-extension]  ?

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (that does not use 3rd party APIs like `FileUtils`). 3) Look to [`File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) for filtering the `.mp3` files from the rest. 4) The title of the post does not match up well with the question.  Could you change one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

I find the NIO.2 approach using GLOBs or custom filter the cleanest solution. Check out this example on how to use GLOB or filter example in the attached link:

```
Path directoryPath = Paths.get("C:", "Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/src/java/nio/file");

if (Files.isDirectory(directoryPath)) {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directoryPath, "*.mp3")) {
        for (Path path : stream) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

For more information about content listing and directory filtering visit [Listing and filtering directory contents in NIO.2](http://jakubstas.com/listing-filtering-directory-contents-nio2)

Answer (score 1):

`File` provides an ability to filter the file list as it's begin generated.

```
File[] listOfFiles = sourceDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
    }
});
```

Now, this has a number of benefits, the chief among which is you don't need to post-process the list, again, or have two lists in memory at the same time.

It also provides pluggable capabilities.  You could create a `MP3FileFilter` class for instance and re-use it.

Comment: Generally speaking, does `listFiles` return all of the files within a directory as well?

Comment: @JoshM Generally speaking `listFiles` has to iterate all the files in the directory any way to generate the list.  The `FileFilter` allows the method to discard those `File`s you don't want and return only those you do.  This means you don't need to double process the list...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ext.endWith(".mp3")){
 //do what ever you want 
}
```

Comment: This is no good. Imagine you need to process only .mp3 files and you have 10^10 archives and only one of these ends with .mp3. With your method you will do 10^10 innecesary if statements.